# How do i get him to stay awake until I say goodbye?

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, voice-recognition

Building my own voice assistant. After each command is given and response returned, I have to wake him again. I want him to be awake for all queries. stuck, please help. sorry if it seems vague.

```
WAKE = 'allen'
while True:
    text = mic_input()

    if text.count(WAKE) > 0:
        toSpeak.say("yes sir")
        toSpeak.runAndWait()
        text = mic_input()
        process_text(text)
        toSpeak.runAndWait()
```

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? Your code never checks `text` for `"goodbye"`. It'd help a lot if you made a [mre] including complete but minimal code, example input, expected output, and actual output. For the sake of example, forget the voice aspect for now and just use `input()` and `print()`. If you want more tips, see [ask].

Comment: I did that originally, but then my question was removed because I "didn't have a specific problem" and "shouldn't ask for troubleshooting of code". also, its not about the goodbye part, the problem is with my loop. for some reason it doesnt repeat unless i WAKE again. im ok with writing the goodbye portion later but i want the continuous loop for before I input the killswitch if you will

Comment: everything else before the code i provided is just commands. I.E "open excel", "search google", "calculate math", etc.

Comment: It's not just commands. These names are not defined: `mic_input, toSpeak, process_text`

Comment: they are defined earlier in the code and inside their own respective functions. I didn't think I needed to post every line of code. I hope i dont sound rude but when i asked this question before and posted the code with everything defined and such i was flagged for being to broad

Comment: the assistant works, he does everything I ask. i just have to say 'Allen' after each response

Comment: You need to have an "awake" flag.  When you hear "Allen", you set the flag.  When you hear "goodbye", you clear the flag.  In between, what are you planning?  Just ignore the microphone?

Comment: The plan is always listening, essentially like my own google home device. I can wake on command but close when I am finished communicating all my stupid thoughts. you have been most helpful btw. I haven't heard of flags before, but i will surely look them up. if they are some common thing then bear with me ive only had one class of computer science. im a mechanical engineer by trade

Comment: Are you talking about [this question](/q/70268011/4518341)? It wasn't deleted, just closed (though it may be auto-deleted within a few weeks). It was closed because you dumped in your whole project with no effort at debugging it. We're not going to debug your entire project for you; you need to isolate the problem first. Please, read [mre], emphasis on the *minimal*. Also take the [tour] if you haven't already, to understand how SO works.

Comment: You don't sound rude, don't worry. SO works differently than other sites and it can take some getting used to.

Comment: i did debug it. several times. it did what i was asking it to do when i created it. at every point except staying awake. i couldnt figure that out so i posted a question. i have seen some fairly silly and overly minimal questions posted on this site so i figured that if i had my code figured out and only had one issue, i would be fine

Comment: but i guess not lol

Comment: i guess maybe it didnt come off that way

Comment: so i thought that if i just posted the loop that was supposed to control the entire program id be ok ya know. but as you say you cant see any of the definitions, it makes me confused of what im even supposed to post if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand problem but I would use variable `True/False` to control if it awake

```
WAKE = 'allen'

awake = False

while True:
    text = mic_input()

    if not awake:
        if text.count(WAKE):
            awake = True
            toSpeak.say("yes sir")
            toSpeak.runAndWait()
    else:        
        if text.count('goodbye'):
            awake = False
            toSpeak.say("bye")
            toSpeak.runAndWait()
        elif text.count('time'): 
            process_text('it is time to eat something')
            toSpeak.runAndWait()
        else:
            process_text("I don't understand " + text)
            toSpeak.runAndWait()
```